# Can't reach specific XML element using XMLReader

Tags: java, xml, parsing, jaxb

I need to parse the following xml file using xmlreader in order to then unmarshall the parts using JAXB.

```
<parents>
    <moms>
      <mom>
       ...
      </mom>
       <mom>
       ...
      </mom>
   ...
    </moms>
    <dads>
      <dad>
       ..
      </dad>
      ..
      ..
    </dads>
</parents>
```

I can reach the `<moms>` element, but I am unable to reach the `<dads>` element , either using that same Xmlreader variable or a totally new one. I'm only able to find the moms element and then enter the hierarchy there...

the code :

```
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream( file );
        xmlStreamReader = Utils.getXMLStreamReader( fileInputStream, "UTF-8" );
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Moms.class, Dads.class);
        unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
        xmlStreamReader.nextTag();

            xmlStreamReader.require( XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT, null, "parents" ); 
            xmlStreamReader.nextTag();
            xmlStreamReader.nextTag();
            xmlStreamReader.require( XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT, null, part );
            xmlStreamReader.require( XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT, null, "parents" ); 
           while ( xmlStreamReader.getEventType() == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT )
    {
        String localName = xmlStreamReader.getLocalName();

        if ( localName.equals("dads") )
        {
            xmlStreamReader.nextTag();
        }


        if (xmlStreamReader.getEventType() ==XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS) 
        {
            xmlStreamReader.next();
        }
    }                   
    }
```

Comment: Can you include an example of your code?

Comment: What is your Handlers/Resolvers code?

Comment: @KirillLebedev - What are Handlers/Resolvers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the following XML

```
<parents>
  <moms>
    <mom>A</mom>
    <mom>B</mom>
  </moms>
  <dads>
    <dad>C</dad>
  </dads>
</parents>
```

the code below

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("...");
XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(is);
while (xsr.hasNext()) {
  if (xsr.next() == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT
      && xsr.getLocalName().equals("dad")) {

    if (xsr.next() == XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS)
      System.out.println(xsr.getText());
  }
}
```

prints *C*.

I think you somehow managed to jump over the *dad* elements. Try simplify your logic. All that *require* and *nextTag* business seems wrong to me. Also, while I'm not sure, but the conditional statement in your *while* seems silly. Use *xmlStreamReader.hasNext* instead and jump out of the loop if you're done.